# Overlapping images in CSS with divs

Tags: html, css, center

[image]

I have 2 images I would like to look similar to this photo (sorry about the quality, the PSD for the site is scattered so I whipped an image together in a few mins to show what I meant).

My first image is the logo - which is a png of the guy with glasses, the trail and the title.

The second image is the blue box, which I would like to be a form for users to put their email address on.

My HTML tags are this:

```
<body id="home">
    <div id="main" method="post" action="">
    <img id="Smarty" src="images/logo.png" />

</div>

       <div id="box" method="post" action="">
       <img id="Form" src="images/form.png" />

</div>
```

And my css follows:

```
 #home #main {
margin-top: 10%;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto; }

 #home #main #box {

margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto; }
```

The goal is to have the image looking like the attached photo, with it all centered relative to the size of the users screen.  I already have the background working to scale accordingly, but cannot for the life of me figure out how to overlap existing PNGs in CSS with % values rather than fixed pixel values.

Thanks for any guidance!

EDIT:

This code puts my logo in the right place (center and 8% down from the top of the page):

```
  #wrapper #main {

margin-top: 8%;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
text-align:center; 
display:block; }


  #wrapper #main #box{

margin-top: 8%;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
position: relative;
text-align:center;
display:block; }
```

But the box is still below the logo, and to the far left.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't You use these images as backgrounds?

Small example.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="smarty">
    <div id="form">
        <!-- The content -->
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#smarty {
    background-image: url('images/logo.png');
}

#form {
    background-image: url('images/form.png');
}
```

P.S.

IE6 hate png with alpha.

Comment: rather than blocks?  Well my form image will need text and a submission box in it, is using as a background a more acceptable method?

Comment: @Michas, yeah: but, y'know, what on the web *doesn't* IE6 hate with a vengeance?

Comment: @Sapp: I've added small example. It is much easier to put something on background image than on image from img tag. It's all.

Comment: @David Thomas: The pngs without alpha works nice. It may be easier to use opaque images.

Comment: @Michas: Does setting the images as backgrounds rather than divs give me better leverage in overlapping and editing?

Answer (score 1):

try adding position relative to one of the divs or use float (right and left)

```
#home #main {
margin-top: 10%;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto; }

 #home #main #box {

margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto; 

position: relative;}
```

Comment: So make my logo absolute and my box relative to the logo?

Answer (score 0):

you can use multiple images in single div with overlapping.
it's easy way for overlapping multiple images

```
#box{
  background: url (bg1.png) no-repeat top left,url (bg2.png) no-repeat top center,url (bg3.png) no-repeat top center;
}
```

Comment: what on earth does that css do? sorry for my ignorance

Comment: @JaysonRagasa it's a css3 property called **multiply background** read this for more https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Using_CSS_multiple_backgrounds